# Unable to get submat of an image in OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Ok, I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong. Here is what I want. I am actually capturing image frame from camera. Now, when the camera loads, the whole image is shown. Then I have been able to draw a rectangle at the center of the camera frame. So far so good. Now, here is what I want. I want to store that rectangular section in a Mat and blur out the section outside the rectangular section in the image frame.
For now, I tried to show only the rectangular section in the camera frame but for some reason, the frame is all black.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mrgba = inputFrame.rgba();


        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float h = mrgba.cols();
        float w = mrgba.rows();


        int centerx = (int) (mrgba.width()*0.5);
        int  centery = (int) (mrgba.height() * 0.5);
        Rect rect = new Rect(centerx,centery,100,100);

        Mat submat = mrgba.submat(rect);
        Mat result = new Mat(rect.width, rect.height, mrgba.type());
        submat.copyTo(result);


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Try with `return result.clone();`

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `Mat result = new Mat(rect.height, rect.width, mrgba.type());` ?